# Why is the og:image meta data not being formatted property with the reactive data?

Tags: nuxt.js, meta-tags, nuxtjs3

Why is the following meta tag image path getting formatted differently when using `og:image` meta property?

The variable for the `og:image` property in my Nuxt3 app is like so:

```js
const { data: post } = await useFetch(`/api/posts/${route.params.id}`, {
  key: `/post/${route.params.id}`
})

useServerSeoMeta({
  title: () => `${post.value.data?.title} - Pixstery`,
  ogTitle: () => `${post.value.data?.title} - Pixstery`,
  description: () => post.value.data?.content,
  ogDescription: () => post.value.data?.content,
  ogImage: () =>
    config.public.imagekitBaseURL +
    post.value.data?.imagePath +
    '&tr=w-1200,fo-auto,dpr-auto',
  twitterCard: 'summary_large_image'
})
```

The observed data for `imagePath` is:
`users%2F5cnu6iDlTsa5mujH2sKPsBJ8OKH2%2Fposts%2Ffrench-biplane_jZqm?alt=media&token=c2837ec7-3679-4d6c-8509-2920f9200749` but when I view the `og:image` meta in source code, it's "broken" because it is being formatted like so:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://ik.imagekit.io/<REMOVED>/users-biplane_jZqm?alt=media&token=c2837ec7-3679-4d6c-8509-2920f9200749&tr=w-1200,fo-auto,dpr-auto">`

Notice the `users-biplane...` change ...it should be the path `users%2F5cnu6iDlTsa5mujH2sKPsBJ8OKH2%2Fposts%2Ffrench-biplane_jZqm?alt=media&token=c2837ec7-3679-4d6c-8509-2920f9200749` instead.

Is the `%2F` causing an escape issue or some sort?